# How to save the result of a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

```
function priceDiscountSeries(originalPrice, discountSeries) {
    let netPrice = originalPrice;
    for (let i = 0; i < discountSeries.length; i++) {
        netPrice = originalPrice * (1 - discountSeries[i]);
    }
    return netPrice;
}

console.log(priceDiscountSeries(94_500, [0.40, 0.10, 0.05]));
```

What I'm trying to do is to have the result saved on a variable, then use that variable to return another result, which is again saved on the variable itself.

It finds the result of the price in a discount series. It's supposed to return 48,478.5 as the net price but instead returns

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\neoxe\Desktop\disCompute.js"
89775

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.539 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```js
netPrice = originalPrice * (1 - discountSeries[i]);
```

with

```js
netPrice *= (1 - discountSeries[i]);
```

Should give you the result you're looking for.

However, you could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to perform the same operation, having a simple [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the price discount:

```js
const priceDiscount = (price, discount) => price * (1 - discount);

const discountSeries = [0.40, 0.10, 0.05];

console.log(discountSeries.reduce(priceDiscount, 94_500));
```

Answer (score 0):

do this it will save your value to netPrice, or You can create an Array to save it
netPrice = netPrice + originalPrice * (1 - discountSeries[i]);
array[i]=originalPrice * (1 - discountSeries[i]);

Simple Enjoy Coding!